# Use -javaagent without packaging agent into a jar

Tags: java, debugging, javaagents

Is it possible to run `java -javaagent:myagent.jar some.package.Main` without having agent packaged to a jar? Something like `java agent.MyAgent some.package.Main`

I have a source code for an agent and would like to be able to debug it and later change it so it is not needed to use `-javaagent` at all but instead select `some.package.Main` to execute through GUI.

[BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace/pages/UserGuide) is able to connect to a running process using PID or connect to a process using `-javaagent`. I'm looking for something similar to first approach (using PID), but so I can start a process from scratch as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 6 you can use [Attach API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/attach/index.html) to load agent programmatically (without `-javaagent`), but it still requires agent to be packaged as jar.

Comment: Thanks! From the API I can see how to attach an agent to a process that already has been created and I know PID of. Can I do it so I pass in a class with main method?
I want to be able to monitor the process starting up as well.